# Android Studio Two Return Values

Tags: android, android-studio, jsp

I'm writing a code to connect the oracle database with the Android studio. If there is one return value while trying to create a jsp file and connect it with oracle, login is not progressing if there are two return values. Which part should I fix? Thank you.

This is my android studio code

```js
package com.example.schedule.Login;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.schedule.Birth.Kfc_Birth;
import com.example.schedule.R;
import com.example.schedule.RequestHttpURLConnection;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

public class Kfc_Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText sendCode;
    private EditText sendEmpno;
    private EditText sendPwd;

    String code = "";
    String empno = "";
    String password = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kfc_login);
        setTitle("KFC");

        sendCode = findViewById(R.id.kfc_code);
        sendEmpno = findViewById(R.id.kfc_empno);
        sendPwd = findViewById(R.id.kfc_pwd);

        HttpConnection connection;

        final Button send= findViewById(R.id.kfc_btn_login);

        send.setOnClickListener(view -> {

            code = sendCode.getText().toString();
            empno = sendEmpno.getText().toString();
            password = sendPwd.getText().toString();

            if (code.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Put in the code", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(empno.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Put in the num.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }else if(password.equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"put in the password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            URL url = null;
            try {
                String path = getResources().getString(R.string.login_url) + "?";
                String query= "code="+URLEncoder.encode(code,"UTF-8")+
                        "&empno=" + URLEncoder.encode(empno, "UTF-8") +
                        "&password=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
                url = new URL(path  + query);
            } catch (MalformedURLException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            new HttpConnection().execute(url);
        });
    }

    private class HttpConnection extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(URL... urls) {
            String data = "";

            if (urls.length == 0) {
                return "URL is empty";
            }
            try {
                RequestHttpURLConnection connection = new RequestHttpURLConnection();
                data = connection.request(urls[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                data = e.getMessage();
            }
            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String data) {
            super.onPostExecute(data);


            if (data.equals("2")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Kfc_Login.this, Kfc_Birth.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            } else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Fail to login",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my jsp Code.

```js
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.sql.*"
    import = "java.util.*" %>

<%
    String login_fir_recvCode;
    String login_fir_recvNo;
    String login_fir_recvPwd;
    
    String login_sec_recvBirth;
    String login_sec_recvBusiness;
    
    String returns = "";
    String names = "";
   
   try {
      login_fir_recvCode = request.getParameter("code");// android studio value
      login_fir_recvNo = request.getParameter("empno");// android studio value
      login_fir_recvPwd = request.getParameter("password");// android studio value
      
      login_sec_recvBirth = request.getParameter("birthday");// android studio value
      login_sec_recvBusiness = request.getParameter("business");// android studio value
      
      
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvCode);
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvNo);
      System.out.println(login_fir_recvPwd);
      
      System.out.println(login_sec_recvBirth);
      System.out.println(login_sec_recvBusiness);
      
      //DB Connect
      Connection conn = null;
      
      PreparedStatement login_fir_pstmt = null;
      PreparedStatement login_sec_pstmt = null;
      PreparedStatement name_pstmt = null;
      
      ResultSet login_fir_rs = null;
      ResultSet login_sec_rs = null;
      ResultSet name_rs = null;
      
      String login_fir_sql = null;
      String login_sec_sql = null;
      String name_sql = null;
      
      
      try {
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
         conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracl:thin:@ip:1521:orcl", "id", "pwd");
         try {
            login_fir_sql = "SELECT * FROM CREW WHERE CODE= ? AND EMPNO=? AND PASSWORD=?";//Login
            
            login_fir_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(login_fir_sql);
 
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(1,login_fir_recvCode);
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(2,login_fir_recvNo);
            login_fir_pstmt.setString(3,login_fir_recvPwd);
     
            login_fir_rs = login_fir_pstmt.executeQuery();
            
            if (login_fir_rs.next()) {
                if (login_fir_rs.getString("CODE").equals(login_fir_recvCode) && login_fir_rs.getString("EMPNO").equals(login_fir_recvNo) && login_fir_rs.getString("PASSWORD").equals(login_fir_recvPwd)) {
                   returns = "2";
                } else {
                   returns = "1";
                }
             }
            
            login_fir_rs.close();
            login_fir_pstmt.close();
         }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("first login error");
         }
         
         try {
             login_sec_sql = "SELECT * FROM KFC_CREW WHERE BIRTHDAY=? OR BUSINESS_NUMBER=?";//Login
             
             login_sec_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(login_sec_sql);
  
             login_sec_pstmt.setString(1,login_sec_recvBirth);
             login_sec_pstmt.setString(2,login_sec_recvBusiness);
      
             login_sec_rs = login_sec_pstmt.executeQuery();
             
             if (login_sec_rs.next()) {
                 if (login_sec_rs.getString("BIRTHDAY").equals(login_sec_recvBirth)||login_sec_rs.getString("BUSINESS_NUMBER").equals(login_sec_recvBusiness)) {
                   returns = "4";
                } else {
                   returns = "3";
                }
             }
            
             login_sec_rs.close();
             login_sec_pstmt.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Second Login Error");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
         
         try {
             name_sql = "SELECT NAME FROM CREW WHERE EMPNO=? AND PASSWORD=?";//call name    
             name_pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(name_sql);
             name_pstmt.setString(1,login_fir_recvNo);
             name_pstmt.setString(2,login_fir_recvPwd);
      
             name_rs = name_pstmt.executeQuery();
             
             if(name_rs.next()){
                    names=name_rs.getString("NAME"); 
             }
             name_rs.close();
             name_pstmt.close();
          }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("name error");
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
      }
         catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Oracle Connection fail!");
         }
   }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("Server or Oracle Error!");
         }finally {
      out.println(returns); 
      out.println(names);
      System.out.println(returns);
      System.out.println(names);
   }
%>
```

Comment: Have you tried to call the web page with some Http client, like a Postman, Insomnia etc.?